# Read txt file in sas

Tags: sas

I have a very simple question. 
I'm trying to read a txt file in sas. The data set, has 6 variables (columns) one of these variables is qualitative, with elements M and F. 
I use the following code to read the data:

```
data dta;
    infile 'C:\...\dta.txt';
    input ID $ Q y1 y2 y3 y4; 
    run;
```

When I print the data set, I get dots in the column of the qualitative variable (Q), instead of F and M.

What I'm doing wrong. Could you help me?

Comment: Try putting a dollar `$` sign after `Q` in your input statement, so it reads `input ID $ Q $ y1 y2 y3 y4;`. SAS assumes an incoming variable is numeric unless explicitly told otherwise.

Comment: @sasfrog Want to make that an answer so I can upvote it?

Comment: At time of viewing this is the 999th question tagged with the `SAS` tag. Pretend this comment is animated with a lairy border inviting you to click to win an iPad.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try putting a dollar `$` sign after `Q` in your input statement, so it reads:

`input ID $ Q $ y1 y2 y3 y4;`

SAS assumes an incoming variable is numeric unless explicitly told otherwise, which is what the `$` does on an input statement.

Comment: @DanaiC.: great to hear. You can mark my answer as accepted by using the big checkmark so that people of the future (including ourselves) can quickly find the solution :)